# changing a tikz to a Venn diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I would like to change my following code into using Venndiagrams so I can colour the cells more easily and add examples eg 1,2,3 in the natural section. Or is there a better way?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily, scale=0.8]
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 2] in {Natural $\mathbb{N}$ ,Whole numbers   $\mathbb{Z}$ ,Rational $\mathbb{Q}$, Real algebraic $\mathbb{A}$, Real $\mathbb{R}$}
 {\draw (-\Y,-\Y/2) circle ({1.5*\Y} and \Y);
 \node at (1-2*\Y,-1.1*\Y) {\X}; }
 \draw ([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current bounding box.south west)
 rectangle ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0.5cm]current bounding box.north east);
 \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {Types of numbers};
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

any hint or directions would be amazing my solution is so messy its silly.

Comment: Do you mean the `venndiagram` package (https://ctan.org/pkg/venndiagram)? Not sure that package can create something like your diagram, it is for "generating simple two- and three-set Venn diagrams".

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the messy way. I have also only used it for 2,3 set diagrams.